# Phase-shifting of instantaneous eigenstates in the adiabatic approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, approximations, adiabatic

In my book *Quantum Mechanics* by B.H. Bransden and C.J. Joachain, there is a chapter on the adiabatic approximation.

Here, the authors assume that the time-dependent Hamiltonian $\hat{H}(t)$ changes slowly, and expand the state of the system in the instantaneous energy eigenstates $|H_n(t)\rangle$, defined by

$$\tag{0}\hat{H}(t)|H_n(t)\rangle = E_n(t)|H_n(t)\rangle,$$

where $E_n(t)$ are the corresponding instantaneous energy eigenvalues.

The expansion of the system state $|\Phi(t)\rangle$ looks like

$$\tag{E}|\Phi(t)\rangle = \sum_n \phi_n(t) |H_n(t)\rangle e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^t E_n(t) dt},$$

and by plugging this into the Schrödinger equation, they end up with the set of coupled differential equations

$$\tag{1}\frac{d\phi_n}{dt}(t) = -\sum_k \phi_k(t) \langle H_n(t)|\frac{d}{dt}|H_k(t) \rangle e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^t (E_n(t')-E_k(t'))dt'}$$

for the coefficients $\phi_n(t)$.

So far I'm in. But now,  they introduce phase-shifted coefficients

$$\tag{S1} \phi'_n(t) = \phi_n(t)e^{i\int_0^t \beta_n(t')dt'}$$

where the $\beta_n(t)$ are defined as the imaginary part of the products $\langle H_n(t)|\frac{d}{dt}|H_n(t) \rangle$ (which can be shown to be pure imaginary). Then they differentiate and show that these shifted coefficients $\phi'_n(t)$ obey a similar set of differential equations,

$$\tag{2} \frac{d\phi'_n}{dt}(t) = -\sum_{k \neq n} \phi'_k(t) \langle H_n(t)|\frac{d}{dt}|H_k(t) \rangle e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^t (E'_n(t')-E'_k(t'))dt'},$$

where the diagonal terms have now vanished, and new, shifted energy eigenvalues

$$\tag{S2} E'_n(t) = E_n(t)+\hbar\beta_n(t)$$

have been introduced. Finally, they claim that the phase-shift of the coefficients amounts to a corresponding phase shift

$$\tag{S3}|H'_n(t)\rangle = |H_n(t)\rangle e^{-i\int_0^t \beta_n(t') dt'}$$

of the energy eigenstates, and since this phase-shift is arbitrary at each instant time (which is their momentary assumption), one can simply say that the shift has already been made and omit the primes to get

$$\tag{3} \frac{d\phi_n}{dt}(t) = -\sum_{k \neq n} \phi_k(t) \langle H_n(t)|\frac{d}{dt}|H_k(t) \rangle e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^t (E_n(t')-E_k(t'))dt'}.$$

My questions to this are the following:

1. **How can they simply omit the primes from equation (2) when the factor $\langle H_n|\frac{d}{dt}|H_k \rangle$ is still unprimed?** From what I am able to calculate, the primed and unprimed versions of this factor are related by $\langle H'_n|\frac{d}{dt}|H'_k \rangle = e^{i\int_0^t (\beta_n(t')-\beta_k(t'))dt'} \langle H_n|\frac{d}{dt}|H_k \rangle$ for all $k \neq n$. In other words they are not equal, so this move would surely mess up the equation with a mix of phase-shifted and not phase-shifted quantities?
2. **What is the meaning of their claim that the phase-shift of the coefficients (S1) amounts to a corresponding negative phase-shift of the energy eigenstates (S3)?** To me, these two shifts "correspond" in the sense that $\phi_k(t)|H_k(t)\rangle = \phi'_k(t)|H'_k(t)\rangle$ in the expansion (E), but the energy eigenvalues $E_k(t)$ are still unprimed, so again it seems like a bad idea to simply omit the primes and pretend that they are all corresponding.

**EDIT:** I think I found out what's going on here. Initially, I thought that the phase-shifted eigenstates $|H'_n(t)\rangle$ from (S3) actually had eigenvalues $E'_n(t)$ from (S2), because using the Schrödinger equation on such a state gave me

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\tag{X1} \hat{H}(t)|H'_n(t)\rangle &=& i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}(|H_n(t)\rangle e^{-i\int_0^t \beta_n(t')dt}) \\
&=& i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}|H_n(t)\rangle e^{-i\int_0^t \beta_n(t')dt'} +\hbar\beta_n(t)|H_n(t)\rangle e^{-i\int_0^t \beta_n(t')dt'} \\
&=& (E_n(t)+\hbar\beta_n(t))|H_n(t)\rangle e^{-i\int_0^t \beta_n(t')dt'} \\
&=& E'_n(t)|H'_n(t)\rangle,
\end{eqnarray}$$

where I used the Schrödinger equation again to get

$$\tag{X2} i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}|H_n(t)\rangle = \hat{H}(t)|H_n(t)\rangle = E_n(t)|H_n(t)\rangle.$$

But **(X1) and (X2) are both WRONG**: The Schrödinger equation only applies to *the actual state of the system*, not to each and every state I come up with. In other words, the only equation valid for the instantaneous energy eigenstates is the defining equation (0). And because the phase-shifting factor $e^{-i\int_0^t \beta_n(t')dt'}$ is just a constant in each instant, it commutes with the Hamiltonian, giving the exact same instantaneous energy eigenvalues for the shifted eigenstates as for the un-shifted ones:

$$\hat{H}(t)|H'_n(t)\rangle = \hat{H}(t)(|H_n(t)\rangle e^{-i\int_0^t \beta_n(t')dt'}) = E_n(t)(|H_n(t)\rangle e^{-i\int_0^t \beta_n(t')dt'}) = E_n(t)|H'_n(t)\rangle!$$

*Then* the omission of the primes makes sense, but only after I move  the phase factors out of the primed energies and into the matrix element:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d\phi'_n}{dt}(t) &=& -\sum_{k \neq n} \phi'_k(t) \langle H_n(t)|\frac{d}{dt}|H_k(t) \rangle e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^t (E'_n(t')-E'_k(t'))dt'} \\
&=& -\sum_{k \neq n} \phi'_k(t) \langle H_n(t)|\frac{d}{dt}|H_k(t) \rangle e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^t (E_n(t')+\hbar\beta_n(t')-E'_k(t')-\hbar\beta_k(t'))dt'} \\
&=& -\sum_{k \neq n} \phi'_k(t) e^{i\int_0^t (\beta_n(t')-\beta_k(t'))dt'} \langle H_n(t)|\frac{d}{dt}|H_k(t) \rangle e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^t (E_n(t')-E'_k(t'))dt'} \\
&=& -\sum_{k \neq n} \phi'_k(t) \langle H'_n(t)|\frac{d}{dt}|H'_k(t) \rangle e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_0^t (E_n(t')-E_k(t'))dt'}
\end{eqnarray}$$

In my opinion then, the usage of a prime in (S2) is misleading, because $E'_n(t)$ are *not* the eigenvalues of $|H'_n(t)\rangle$ – in fact, they aren't eigenvalues at all! Why the authors even bother to introduce the quantities $E'_n(t)$ is a mystery to me.

If anyone could confirm that this is correct, or wants to add something that can shed light on this, I would be very grateful. Thanks!